# Is there software that can scan for reused R-values?

Tags: transactions, signature, transaction-input, hacking

Is there any up-to-date program that can check for reused R-value for a specific Bitcoin address? (I don't want to scan the whole blockchain, just for a particular address.)

Comment: I'm assuming you will be looking for transaction input data from specific accounts?

Comment: It is not a problem to write such code. I am not familar with taproot signature encodings but checking R values for specific p2pkh address (adresses 1xxxxxx) can be coded in one day ))) If you have synced blockchain on your PC

Comment: I have parsed the entire blockchain and saved on drive. The address has 245 000 input transactions. There is some programmes on github for the purpose but unable to handle 245 000 reading inputs